# time.process_time() printing 'e-xx'

Tags: python, time, printing, floating-point

I am recording the length of time it take to perform each of my functions.

Successful at calculating. However, half the time print contains `e-xx` (xx - digits). Even when casting my answer as `float()`.

```
import time

tic = time.process_time()
a = 1 + 2
print(a)
toc = time.process_time()
print(str(round(float(toc - tic), 8)) + "s")
>>> 3
>>> 4.57e-06s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force the output to match a given format, for example floating point with 8 digits after the decimal as in the MWE, use `str.format()`. Replacing the second `print` command with

`print('{:.8f}s'.format(toc - tic))`

will give the desired output. In my case `0.00020080s`. See [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) for a details of the string formatting syntax.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you